# Ruby on Rails: ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: error when trying to run unit tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to run unit tests on my application, and my original error was "table xx has no column named yy", so in my yml file I changed the fields to id. However, now it gives me this error:

CarsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_car:
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed
How do I fix this and run my tests?

Comment: What's the failing test?

Comment: @SebastianPalma when I run rails test, it doesn't run any of the tests and gives me the error above.

Comment: @SebastianPalma yes, I just edited in the yml files for cars and parts above.

Comment: Make has a validation for `make` and `country`, are they defined in its fixture file?

Comment: @SebastianPalma yes it does, I added the yml file for makes as well.

Comment: In your car fixture, the value for `vin` isn't according to the validations in its model. Try updating that to a value that makes a record valid.

Comment: @SebastianPalma okay, I adjusted it accordingly, however I still get the same not null constraint error when running unit tests

Comment: I suspect this is a `dependent destroy`problem. You are trying to destroy a car,  when a reference to that car exists in the join table. You need to destroy this reference as well. But you can't add a dependent destroy on a has_and_belongs_to relationship.  I would change the relationship to a has_ many `through` and then i would add a 'dependent destroy' option. You will need to rename your models and tables as per rails conventions though for it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create_table "cars_parts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "car_id"
    t.integer "part_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["car_id"], name: "index_cars_parts_on_car_id"
    t.index ["part_id"], name: "index_cars_parts_on_part_id"
  end
```

You have a not null constraint on `created_at` in `cars_parts`.

In the error you can see that it says `created_at` can't be Null:

`SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: cars_parts.created_at`

So in your yml file you need to set created_at:

```
one:
  car_id: 1
  part_id: 1
  created_at: Time.current
  updated_at: Time.current

two:
  car_id: 2
  part_id: 2
  created_at: Time.current
  updated_at: Time.current
```

EDIT:

As Sebastian pointed out, this is not an ideal solution, AR should automatically be adding these timestamps.

The real problem is that you named your model `CarParts` so it's not finding the model.  You should rename the file to `cars_part.rb` and the model name to `CarsPart`.

Other people having this problem were attributing the cause to the model not being found:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23316

Comment: That can explain the error, but is true that that's a document feature of the FixtureSet _If your table/model specifies any of Active Record's standard timestamp columns (created_at, created_on, updated_at, updated_on), they will automatically be set to Time.now_. If this solves the error, then it's something that's going to be needed for every fixture of a model using timestamps.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after I posted my answer, I think the actual problem is that he named his model `CarParts`, instead of `CarPart`.  I read a github issue thread where people were getting this error when the model wasn't found.

Comment: Nice catch! So that could be solved with the proper inflection.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Thank you! I changed my model name to follow convention and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

When you use has_and_belongs_to_many, the join table shouldn't have created/updated_at timestamps and you don't need the CarsParts model (only the table is required, not the model). If you want a CarsParts model, you have to use has_many and has_many :through associations so ActiveRecord handles the join model as an actual model and sets the timestamps

So, you have to options:

1- remove the timestamps on the join table and remove the CarsParts model

or

2- add the right associations and fix the model's table and name:

```
CarPart #not CarsParts
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :part
  self.table_name = 'cars_parts' # the actual plural would be car_parts, not cars_parts

Part
  has_many :car_parts
  has_many :cars, through: :cars_parts

Car
  has_many :car_parts
  has_many :parts, through: :cars_parts
```